# Configuring alot of iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles

I configured a bunch of iPads at my previous job, and I had to do it one at a time.  Granted, there were only like 6 of them, but I am wondering what I would do if I needed to configure a whole bunch of iDevices.  I know at the Apple Store they apply updates on a bunch of them without taking them out of the package, so there must be some sort of way to do this.

Comment: Have you looked at Apple's [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465)? See also http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/ for docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) was made for this exact reason: easy deployment of iOS devices in large numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Of a whole bunch is less than 50 Apple Configurator or a free hosted MDM are in the sweet spot.

More than that, do some research on the various MDM solutions that exist and then decide whether you want to hire interns and employees to do the work manually or hire some software to allow one person to automate the parts of device management you care most about.

Here's a nice place to start when you face this problem:

- http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Comparison_MDM_Providers

Comment: Also - many organizations like to contract out things like this during pilot projects or if it's not their core competency. Say a law firm that bills out at $250 to $350 an hour would gladly hire an IT worker that bills out the same rate but only is needed 20 hours a month. On the other hand, a non-profit with low cash flow would make other decisions about how to spend time and money.